# incorrect results while passing a datetime instead of getdate()

Tags: sql, datetime

I am working on a SQL query which returns all records between two dates from a table as follows

```
select convert(varchar(2),TestDate,108) from dbo.Table 
where TestDate between convert(datetime,convert(varchar,GETDATE(),101))
                   and dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,GETDATE(),101)))
```

The above query works fine and gives me the desired results but when I tried to use a normal date string instead of getdate(), the query returns and empty result as follows

```
select convert(varchar(2),TestDate,108) from dbo.Table 
    where TestDate between convert(datetime,convert(varchar,'2015-12-27 00:00:00.000',101)) and dateadd(day,1,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,2015-12-27 00:00:00.000',101)))
```

The above query returns an empty result set which is not what I wanted.
I tried passing date string in different formats but that didn't work.

**May I know a correct way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you convert dates to a string for comparisons?  Just do the comparisons as dates.

In addition, you can use `datepart()` to extract the hour, rather than using some esoteric format to `convert()`:

```
select datepart(hour, TestDate)
from dbo.Table 
where TestDate between cast(GETDATE() as date) and
                       cast(dateadd(day, 1, getdate()) as date)
```

If you want the hour as a string instead of a number, then use `datename()` rather than `datepart()`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are having an extra CONVERT.
  Wherever you have this

```
convert(varchar,GETDATE(),101)
```

just replace with your date:

```
'2015-12-27 00:00:00.000'
```

because the purpose of the CONVERT function is to translate a Date into a Varchar

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gordon's answer, you can substitute string dates as so:

```
select datepart(hour, TestDate)
from dbo.Table 
where TestDate between cast('2015-12-27 00:00:00.000' as date) and
                       cast(dateadd(day, 1, '2015-12-27 00:00:00.000') as date)
```

Assuming this is for a webapp, be sure to use placeholders instead of actual text to prevent SQL insertion attacks.